# javascript quad equals meaning ====

Tags: javascript, equality

reading through head first JavaScript book came across this but i have never seen four ==== or is just a bad print

[image]

Comment: @StevenPenny I think that's part of the exercise, figuring out which isn't even valid.

Comment: @Barmar man, reminds me why I hated school. Just give me the damn information. Riddles are a terrible way to learn.

Comment: @StevenPenny Maybe the author thinks there *should* be an `====` operator that corresponds to the last description (like Common Lisp's `eq` function).

Comment: I think the most offensive thing is they're trying to teach something about equality, and keep mentioning this guy,

Answer (score 5):

Read the first paragraph carefully:

> we're not sure if each contender matches **zero**, one or more descriptions

It matches zero, but that isn't a printing error.